# SQL - Check if all the columns in one table also exist in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables (say A and B) in a MS SQL DB representing customer transactions. Both share a column (say Column X).

Ideally information in table B is a subset of information in table A.

Can I run a SQL query to check based on Column X if all the values in Table B are present in Table A?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select X
from A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.x = B.X
WHERE B.X IS NULL
```

to get all records from table `A` that are not in table `B`. Or

```
select X
from B
LEFT OUTER JOIN A on A.x = B.X
WHERE A.X IS NULL
```

to get all records from table `B` that are not in table `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the check to see if any table B rows are missing from table A.

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM Table_B b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM Table_A a
                         WHERE a.x = b.x);
```